# Printing a web page will not show a print view and prints blank

Tags: html, css, angularjs, printing, preview

I created tables in a web page that I need to print.  On the main page I have a printerFriendly button that opens a new tab that shows just the table and content I need printed.  When I go to the new tab and try to print or get a print preview, it is completely blank.  There is some setting or something in the code I can do to fix this?  I am also using angularjs. This happens in Chrome and IE. Any help is appreciated.
*If any code needs to be shown, please let know.  Not sure if it is the code or the print settings.

**This code gets content to appear in the print preview**
**UPDATED**

```
   @media print {

    body *{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #101010;
        background: #f6f5fa;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  #section-to-print, #section-to-print *{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

   #section-to-print2, #section-to-print2 *{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print2 {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

}
```

Comment: The code above gets content to appear in the print preview, but now all the content is meshed together.  There are two sections of content and they both merge at the top.  How can I space out the content better for the print preview?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, its showing content in print preview.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avinashMaddy/otbmjLjt/)

HTML:

```
    <a href="javascript:window.print()">Print this page</a>
    <br>
    <div id="section-to-print">
      I crea    ted tables in a web page that I need to print. On the main page I have a printerFriendly button that opens a new tab that shows just the table and content I need printed. When I go to the new tab and try to print or get a print preview, it is completely blank. There is some setting or something in the code I can do to fix this? I am also using angularjs. This happens in Chrome and IE. Any help is appreciated. *If any code needs to be shown, please let know. Not sure if it is the code or the print settings.
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
        @media print {
        body *{
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #101010;
            background: #f6f5fa;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
      #section-to-print, #section-to-print *{
        visibility: visible;
      }
      #section-to-print {
        position:absolute; 
        left:0;
        top:0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I was able to do this by applying an id to the two sections that I want printed.  'id="section-to-print" ' for the header and 'id="section-to-print2" ' for the table.  Ill update the code above.  For some reason the header and the table, when I view the print preview, are shown on top of each other.  I want them both to be clearly visible.  Any idea how to do this?  I also want the print preview to show the color that is visible on the table and now just in black and white.